# SSIS - Fetch Records Based On Condition

Tags: ssis

how to fetch records based on a condition
eg: I have 100 records in my table. Each time I would like to fetch 10 records at a time and then next set of 10 records until the table data ends.

Comment: Why is this required? It doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

First, Not sure why you would want to do that. You could specify the batch size in your destination.

But if you had any other significant reason do process 10 records at a time, then you use a foreach loop. There is no FOR..LOOP inside a data flow task. 
  option #1. Get the record count in the control flow, then create a for loop container and assign the variables. Inside the container, use a dataflow task and filter the source using the variables and process them.

NM